# Use <strong> and <b> tags at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I aware that CKEditor, by default, overrides the `<b>` tag with the `<strong>` tag. I'm also aware that we may change the one that gets overriden.

The problem is that I've created a function that wraps the selected text with `<b>` when you click a custom button, but I still need the `<strong>` to be working.

```
    exec : function( editor ) {
        var textoSelecionado = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
        var novoSubtitulo = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("b");
        novoSubtitulo.setText(textoSelecionado);
        editor.insertElement(novoSubtitulo);
      }
});
```

So I can't override none of them.

This has to do with the final use of the text inside of the `<textarea>`. The source text will be posted on a blog. On this blog, the text inside a `<b>` tag receives a custom style. The text inside a `<strong>` tag gets bold as it should. Unfortunately, I can't change this rule, so I'll have deal with this somehow.

I've been playing around with `config.coreStyles_bold`, no progress so far.

I've tried `config.coreStyles_bold = { element: 'strong', overrides: false };`, but I'm not sure how this property works xD.

Answer (score 0):

When ever the html code  and  ,the program shows the same output if we put together also we will get the same output.necause it goes like left to right  in order at that time so it get the same out put .